# When to use div instead of semantic html

Tags: html, css

So as a beginner in web development and learning HTML I learned semantic HTML, and now whenever I am trying to create something with HTML and CSS I search for semantic elements for that thing.

While trying to clone an Instagram post, I searched for which semantic element is used as a container for the header part. I learned to use a `<div>` for flow content, but when should I use `<div>` instead of semantic HTML?

Also, what should I do if I can't find the right semantic element for the thing I am creating using HTML and CSS?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about semantics as a beginner. but be careful & use the right HTML

Comment: for e.g. don't place block elements inside inline-elements.

Comment: Probably [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/article), but there isn't really a "right" answer.

Answer (score 1):

A div is a generic element [that has no meaning](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/grouping-content.html#the-div-element).

> Authors are strongly encouraged to view the div element as an element
> of last resort, for when no other element is suitable.

Semantics for elements can often be gray areas and opinion. You do the best you can by reading [the specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/) and basing your decision on their intended use.